# Trying to call on a class in Python

Tags: python, class, object, parameters

```
class Spillebrett:
    def _init_ (self, rader, kolonner):
        self._rader=rader
        self._kolonner=kolonner
```

I have written this in one file, and in another I have written the following

from spillebrett import Spillebrett

```
def main():
    nyttspillebrett=Spillebrett()
    nyttspillebrett(input("Fyll inn antall rader\n"), input("Fyll inn antall kolonner\n"))
```

But I get error: `TypeError: 'Spillebrett' object is not callable`

Why is the Object not callable?

Answer (score 3):

To say an object is callable means that you can call it like so:

```
my_obect()
```

Using parentheses like that is *calling*. So functions are callable e.g. `max(1,2,3)`, class-objects are callable: `my_instance = MyClass()` etc. You've defined a class, the class itself is callable, indeed, you've done that here:

```
nyttspillebrett=Spillebrett()
```

However, you are trying to call the *instance* of your class, but your instance isn't callable. Instead, you probably wanted:

```
nyttspillebrett = Spillebrett(input("Fyll inn antall rader\n"), input("Fyll inn antall kolonner\n"))
```

Note, however, this still won't work because you need to change your `_init_` to `__init__`, notice, it is *two* underscores: `__` instead of `_`

Note that an object from a user-defined class can be made callable by implementing the `__call__` method, but that is likely not what you want to do here.

Comment: Instance can be callable if `__call__` method is defined for the class.

Comment: @anupsabraham yes, they can. But that is almost certainly not what the OP wants, and I think that would just be confusing, but good point.

Comment: Yeah. True. Just stated it if in case you want to include it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

it's `__init__` not `_init_`.

I'm making the assumption that you're posting your actual code.